# Tree type is not supported when creating new Angular project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm new to Angular. I installed Angular CLI from Angular.io, 
but I get this error:

> "Tree type is not supported"

when creating a new Angular project.

[image]

Comment: Something to keep an eye on: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11707

Answer (score 1):

- reinstall global @angular/cli

> Finally removed `yarn.lock` and `node_modules` and installed again worked
>   for me. This could help someone who has trouble now.

Comment: i don't have yarn.lock , and i reinstalled global @angular/cli many times with diffrerent methods , but nothing changes

Comment: He meant to say, remove `yarn.lock` or `package.json` with `node_modules`. This worked for me. I was having issue generating a module.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved uninstalled angular cli global and reinstalling it again, did you tried that?

Comment: Yes i did , but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with different cases, ng new, and ngrx commands...

Please track this issue
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11707

Just downgrade CLI to 6.0.8 should work.

Comment: after downgrade , when creating new project , this error comes
" Invalid rule result: Function(). "

Comment: @AyoubGhozzi please refer this comment. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11663#issuecomment-408033335

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading npm to 6.4.1 solved issue for me

`sudo npm update -g`